# How to see what g++ command-lines Boost.Build invokes (1.33.1)

Tags: boost, bjam, building, tdm-mingw, import-libraries

I'm scratching my head, trying to figure out why the import libraries are not generated when I build the Boost libraries on my machine. More specifically, building the DLLs works fine, but where I would previously (i.e. before I reinstalled my machine) generate the import libraries correctly.

Some specs:

- Boost 1.33.1
- g++ 4.3.3 TDM-1 release for Windows
- Building with `gcc` toolset from MS Dos command-line prompt
- UnxUtils (after 14-04-03)

The command-line that invokes bjam.exe looks like this:

```
"C:\.../boost_1_33_1/tools/build/jam_src/bin.ntx86/bjam.exe" --debug-configuration -d2 -q --builddir=C:/.../trunk/XTemp/gcc.debug/boost_1_33_1 toolset=gcc threading=multi define=BOOST_WINDOWS define=_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS linkflags=-shared-libgcc runtime-link=shared variant=debug --v2  linkflags=-out-implib=boost_thread.lib
```

This used to work wonderfully before and produced the desired file `boost_thread.lib`, but not anymore. I really don't know what's going on and **I would like to know exactly what the linker receives on the command-line and what it thinks it should do with it**.

Thanks,

Carl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-d2` should give you exactly what you are looking for.  I'm surprised it hasn't worked.  Perhaps it is hidden in other messages.  Try omitting the `--debug-configuration` and replacing `-d2` with `-d+2`.  The latter will print the commands bjam invokes in addition to bjam non-debug messages.

Comment: It works when leaving in --debug-configuration as well. But the -d+2 did it. Thanks!